# How do i preview composables that require things from resources?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have the following preview function:

```
@Preview
@Composable
fun PreviewScreen(){
    Icon(bitmap = /*ImageBitmap instance*/, null)
}
```

To get an `ImageBitmap instance` i have to have the access to the resources to get a drawable. But i can get them only from a context such as activity.

**So how do i preview composables that require things from resources? How do i get the resources in a preview function in compose ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ImageVector` and then use `Drawable` Resouce like `XML`.

**Example**

```
@Preview
@Composable
fun Stack011(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
        Icon(imageVector = ImageVector.vectorResource(id = R.drawable.YOUR_IMAGE), null)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Jetpack Compose, you can use multiple `Icon` overloads. One of those takes a parameter of type `Painter`. With its help, you can display an image from resources without using Context. The other overloads in the implementation convert the input parameters to type `Painter`, so you can use those too if you're comfortable with it.

For example:

```
@Preview
@Composable
fun PreviewScreen() {
    Icon(
        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_launcher_background),
        contentDescription = null,
        tint = Color.Unspecified
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can take context from `LocalContext` like the following:

```
@Preview
@Composable
fun PreviewScreen(){
    val value = LocalContext.current.resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.drag_svgrepo_com, null)

    Icon(bitmap = value.toBitmap().asImageBitmap(), null)
}
```